# How to get the string value of ExecuteCommand (or ExecuteQuery) from LINQ?

Tags: c#, string, linq

very simple question here:

I've got a LINQ query that then runs through a foreach loop.

Inside of that foreach, I'm calling ExecuteCommand through LINQ to retrieve a single, asymmetrical decrypted value out of that same table. Because of the complexity of the query, I had to go through ExecuteCommand.

Now my simpler question is... how do I retrieve that value from there? I know it's just going to be one single value, so I don't need to loop through it or anything.

I've tried a `string myString = db.ExecuteCommand("command goes here");` to no avail. It won't even let me run it through its own foreach afterward.

Anyway, my brain drain is getting to me on this one. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Could you post the code? What do you mean when you say "it won't even let me run through its own foreach afterward." If you have a foreach statement which is not being entered, then it means there are no items to iterate over. Does your command actually return a value?

Answer (score 3):

Please try like this.

```
string result = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("SQL Command").Single()
```

This is similar as ExecuteScalar() method, if just want to return single value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ExecuteQuery()  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

ExecuteCommand() returns the number of affected rows.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the ExecuteCommand method is just an integer with the number of rows affected by the command.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx

If you want to actually receive data, you need to use one of the ExecuteQuery overloads.

This will return an IEnumerable with the type that you specify. Since you know its going to be just a single value, this method seems worth looking at in order to actually get your value:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357287.aspx